# Attempting to extend <asp:BoundField />

Tags: html, asp.net, vb.net, custom-controls, custom-data-attribute

I am attempting to extend the ASP:BoundField and override the InitializeDataCell event to do custom data binding. I created a class that inherits from System.Web.UI.WebControls.BoundField (I will post some code below). I am having problems with the Registration tag in the HTML and I don't know if the Registration tag is wrong or if the class code is wrong. The Class code:

```
Imports System
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Configuration
Imports System.Web
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Web.UI
Imports System.Web.UI.WebControls

Namespace cc_custom
    Public Class cc_custom
        Inherits System.Web.UI.WebControls.BoundField


    <DefaultValue("")> _
    Public Property TestData As String
        Get
            Dim val As Object = MyBase.ViewState("TestData ")
            If val IsNot Nothing Then
                Return DirectCast(val, String)
            End If
            Return String.Empty
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            If Not Object.Equals(value, MyBase.ViewState("TestData ")) Then
                MyBase.ViewState("TestData ") = value
                Me.OnFieldChanged()
            End If
        End Set
    End Property


        Protected Overrides Sub InitializeDataCell(cell As DataControlFieldCell, rowState As DataControlRowState)
            If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(Me.TestData) Then
                Dim oLabel As New Label
                AddHandler oLabel.DataBinding, New EventHandler(AddressOf Me.OnLabelDataBind)
                cell.Controls.Add(oLabel)
            End If
        End Sub

        Protected Sub OnLabelDataBind(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
            Dim control As Control = DirectCast(sender, Control)
            Dim namingContainer As Control = control.NamingContainer
            Dim dataValue As Object = Me.GetValue(namingContainer)

            If TypeOf control Is Label Then
                TryCast(control, Label).Text =  'Call to library_function(Me.TestData) will go here
            Else
                MyBase.OnDataBindField(sender, e)
            End If

        End Sub

    End Class
End Namespac
```

The Registration Tag in the HTML

```
<%@ Register Namespace="cc_custom" Assembly="cc_custom " TagPrefix="tzc"  %>
```

And finally the Gridview:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvTest" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <Columns>
        <tzc:cc_custom TestData="OrderDate" />                
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

The error I am getting is "Could not load file or assembly 'cc_custom' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified." I have attempted changing things arround in both the code and the HTML but nothing seems to work. All of the examples I have found use this same pattgern.

Comment: Is the cc_custom assembly within the same assembly as your web application or is it in a separate assembly?  If it is a separate assembly, have you added a reference to that assembly in your web project?

Comment: Same assembly. I actually have gotten this working and it just what I thought. The Namepsace and Class Name have to be referenced correctly in the Regrestration tag and the column tag in the HTML and also the assembly attribute was not even needed.